# Combine 2 Tables that share IDs with one to many relationships to display in sequence where columns don't relate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

Good Afternoon,

I'm looking for a way to display information from two tables that share a one to many relationship with the same ID.

For example.  I have one table; lets call it `TableA`.  And the Other `TableB`.  `AppointmentNum` and `VisNum` are ID's that are the "same" yet labeled differently.

```
**TableA:**                              **TableB**
AppointmentNum     CodeSubmitted         VisNum         CodeCharged
123456             99396                 123456         081003     
123456             81003                 123456         099396
789101             99395                 123456         099420
789101             G0444                 789101         099395
789101             99420                 789101         099420
789101             90471                 654321         090471
654321             99396                 654321         090715
654321             90715                 654321         099396
                                         654321         G0444
```

The ultimate goal is to utilize a query that combines this data so it can be displayed neatly in a table.  For example...

```
ID                 CodeSubmitted      CodeCharged
123456             99396              081003     
123456             81003              099396
123456                                099420
789101             99395              099395
789101             G0444              099420
789101             99420              099420
789101             90471                 
654321             99396              090715
654321             90715              099396
654321                                G0444
654321                                090471
```

I've tried to achieve this using UNIONS, JOINS, etc, but to no success.  For example this simple code:

```
SELECT appnum, code AS a, '' AS b
FROM TableA
WHERE appnum IN (123456, 789101, 654321)

UNION

SELECT visnum, '' AS a, code AS b
FROM TableB
WHERE visnum IN (123456, 789101, 654321) `
```

Will return THIS:

```
appnum      a        b
123456               081003
123456               099396
123456               099420
123456      81003   
123456      99396   
789101               099395
789101               099420
789101      99395   
789101      G0444   
654321               090471
654321               090715
654321               099396
654321               G0444
654321      90471   
654321      90715   
654321      99396   
654321      99420
```

This is close, but doesn't exactly get me there.  I will be using SSRS to display this report that will run off of my query.  Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: You have both mysql and sql-server tagged here. Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using MS SS 2008.  T-SQL

Comment: Perfect. I believe the Full Outer Join example below will do the trick then.

Comment: Thank you for editing my entry btw.  I appreciat that greatly.

Comment: I appreciate your follow up.  The goal is to create a report to show the disparancies per "visit" for codes entered vs. codes billed for said visit.  The number of codes entered could be even, or lopsided between entered/billed for any visit.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I'd say the following should do it:

```
SELECT ISNULL(T1.appnum, T2.visitnum) AS appnum, ISNULL(T1.cptcode, '') AS a, ISNULL(T2.cptcode, '') AS b
FROM xfersubmittedcharges T1
    FULL JOIN IDX_InvVis T2 ON
        T1.appnum = T2.visitnum
WHERE T1.appnum IN (16519736, 16526474, 17285204) OR T2.visitnum IN (16519736, 16526474, 17285204);
```

But clearly the appnum/visitnum column is not unique (so they can't be PKs), and you don't say how exactly the two tables should be matched up.

Comment: Yes, sorry you are correct they are not PKs.  They are IDs that can have many attributes shared to them.  In this instance the two tabls can be associated on TableA.AppointmentNum and TableB.VisNum.  

The types of charges (Submitted or Billed) dictate which table the belong to.  The goal ultimately is to track any discrepancies between Submitted and Billed charges per visit by generating a list.  This list can be even, or uneven on wither column per visit.  Did I explain this better?  And thank you.